# using all the constants with a pattern in QtCreator or vim

Tags: c++, vim, pattern-matching, qt-creator

I use vim or QtCreator as my C++ editors, my problem is the following:

suppose that in the library that I'm currently using there are a lot of constants in the form `NUMBER_OF_<something>` like `NUMBER_OF_PLANETS_IN_THE_UNIVERSE`, `NUMBER_OF_ATOMS_IN_THINGS`, `NUMBER_OF_WEBSITES` ... you get the idea ...

now, I have a lot of this constants in my library and I would like to use the ones that are fitting a specific pattern as argument of the same method over and over, like so

```
std::cout << "NUMBER_OF_*" << NUMBER_OF_* << "\n"
```

there is an easy way to do this without going nuts in QtCreator and/or Vim ?

Answer (score 1):

In `vim`, you can do something like:

```
:r!grep 'define \<NUMBER_OF' files.where.are.the.constants.h
```

then you can delete de lines you don't want, mark the input block with SHIFT-V and

```
:'<'>s,#define *\(\<NUMBER_OF.*\>\).*,    std::cout << "\1" << \1 << "\\n",g
```

Comment: at this point it's easier to use vim in visual mode to copy everything from the header and put it in the file ... but I never talked about a single file ... that's my problem, the only thing I have is a namespace.

Comment: I said `files` where are the constants. :D